# If my development machine is slow and has low end specifications, why can't I just rent a VM on Azure?

Tags: development-process, azure, virtual-machine

I need 16GB RAM on my development machine to do some Android programming but I can't really afford to buy a new one. So, what's there to stop me from just creating a VM on Azure, use it for just a few hours every day (since its billed per second) and save a lot of costs? If I am using Azure's spot instances, I am getting a significant amount of savings, since I don't care about 24x7 deployment anyway.

Comment: OK, so why do you think you cannot do that?

Comment: @VLAZ, because nobody else other than me is talking about it online. I checked a lot of forums, sites, etc., but nobody seems to care about this particular usage of a cloud VM. People are constantly debating various tech specs they need in their dev machine, but nobody says the solution is to just get a VM on the cloud. So I assumed there was some constraint. I am trying out an Azure VM right now to see if it so.

Comment: You could simply try to see if it works for you

Comment: You can. There are even people who use cloud servers for gaming. Of course, this won't work if you need to connect specific periphery, e.g. if you have to connect a phone via USB. And you'll need to pick a data center close to you in order to get good latencies.

Answer (score 2):

AWS offer a remote desktop product which maintains state and basically acts like a normal desktop.

At first I was skeptical of how fast this kind of thing would be for heavy tasks like running a dozen VS instances etc. But I was pleasantly surprised.

If you have a good internet connection it works well.

I think you will find the cost works out more expensive than a local machine over the life time of a PC. Which you could well last for say 5 years these days.

Plus obviously you need a PC of some sort even if its low spec to access the remote machine.

One key thing with mobile development is the ability to deploy your app to a real device. If you cant plug a usb cable in directly you might find this problematic.